# Evaluate $ \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin (3x)}{3x}\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the following limit? Is it possible using L'Hospital's rule?

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left (\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \right)^{\large{1/x}}$$

Comment: I didn't put that tag. Somebody edited it later.

Comment: Oh, I see. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^{1/x}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/x}\right)^3=\left(\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle1/x\cdot\ln((\sin x)/x)}\right)^3$$
Now you can use L'Hôpital's rule to compute the limit (used twice here):
\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\sin x)-\ln x}{x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-x\sin x-\cos x}{2x}=0\end{align*}
So the original limit was $(e^0)^3=1^3=1$.

Comment: The first equality doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain?

Comment: @FromCuba Substitute $x\mapsto x/3$.

Comment: I think I got it now: Your are replacing $x$ for $3x$ in the firs equality correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Put $y = (\frac{ \sin 3x}{3x})^{1/x} $. Hence,

$$ \ln y = \frac{ 1}{x} \ln(\frac{\sin 3x}{3x})$$

Use now hospitals rules on the RHS to obtain

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{3x \cos3x - \sin 3x }{3x^2} }{\frac{ \sin 3x}{3x}} = ...$$

Answer (score 0):

since $t= e^{\log t}$ and $e(\cdot)$ is a continuous function, you can rewrite the limit as 
$$
e^{\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log \frac{\sin 3t}{3t}}{t}}
$$
Now both numerator and denominator in the limit converge to 0, so you can use L'Hospital's rule. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks for help.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Using $\log(\lim a_n)=\lim(\log a_n)$ we can solve this ....

$$\lim_{x\to o}\left(\log\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^{\frac 1 x}\right)
=\lim_{x\to o}\left({\frac 1 x}\log\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to o}\left(\frac{\log\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)} {x}\right)$$

Now Use L,Hospital rule, to obtain the limit,
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac 1 {\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)}\left(\frac{9x\cos 3x-3\sin 3x}{\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^2}\right)\right)=0\quad \ldots\ldots(1)$$
Now,$$\lim_{x\to o}\left(\frac {\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^{\frac 1 x}=e^0=1$$

I skiped some working in $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that $\log u\sim u-1$ when $u\to 1$.

Then you get
$$
\frac 1x \log \frac {\sin 3x}{3x} \sim \frac 1x\frac {\sin 3x - 3x}{3x}
$$
Now apply the l'hospital rule twice to get
$$
\lim  \frac {3\cos 3x - 3}{6x}
= \lim  \frac {-9\sin 3x }{6} = 0
$$
hence the limit is
$$
\exp 1 = e
$$

Answer (score 0):

Admitting that you are allowed to use Taylor $$A=\Big(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \Big)^{\frac 1x}=\Big(\frac{\sin(y)}{y} \Big)^{\frac 3y}$$ So $$\log(A)=\frac 3y \log\Big(\frac{\sin(y)}{y} \Big)$$ Now, for small values of $y$ $$\sin(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ $$\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1-\frac{y^2}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ On the other side, for small values of $z$ $$\log(1+z)=z+O\left(z^2\right)$$ Replace $z$ by $-\frac{y^2}{6}$ and so $$\log\Big(\frac{\sin(y)}{y} \Big)=-\frac{y^2}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ and then $$\log(A)\approx -\frac{y}{2}= -\frac{3x}{2}$$ So, at the limit, $\log(A)=0$ which leads to $A=1$